# replacing items in a line of text not functioning as expected

Tags: c#

I'm currently scanning a csv document and fixing some line ending issues by replacing \r with ~ and then splitting by \n only and then changing all of my ~ back to \r.

My code I believe is correct, i'm able to successfully add in all the ~ but it doesn't take out \r and when I try to reverse it at the end of splitting the lines ~ remains in the document and \r's are still there, assuming they were never removed.

Why is my replace not working as I expect it to?

```
var reader = new StreamReader(path, Encoding.Default);
List<string> lines = new List<string>();

string Lines = reader.ReadToEnd().Replace('\r', '~');

var items = Lines.Split('\n');

foreach (var item in items)
{
    item.Replace('~', '\r');
    lines.Add(item);
}
```

Comment: your last `item.Replace` doesn't assign the result of the replace to anything...

Comment: Try replacing “\r\n” with “~\r\n” and then doing a split at ‘~’.  Replace works on substrings too not just chars.

Comment: @chris that was definitely the problem.

Comment: @SeanO'Neil when i do a .replace it tells me i have to use char and will not let me use a string. is there a certain syntax to get it to accept a string or do i have to pay it an array containing strings?

Comment: @SeanO'Neil nevermind. i can't replace a string with a char. my bad. formatting always seems to get me.

Comment: You could shortcut all this with `Lines.Split(new char[] { '\r', '\n' }, Option.RemoveEmpty)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`item.Replace` doesn't actually change the original string, it returns a new string with the replacement carried out. THat means you *always* need to assign the return value to something. So in this case you need to change

```
item.Replace('~', '\r');
```

to

```
item = item.Replace('~', '\r');
```

(or something similar).